# How to replace special character from HTML document

Tags: android, html, html-parsing

I have a string `"Ã‚Â© 2015"` in my HTML document. I'm parsing the HTML document using `TagHandler`.

```
 opinion_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(description, this, new Html.TagHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {

                }
            }));
```

I'm not handling anything inside `handleTag()`, as the tagHandler itself is handling everything. But it's not parsing the above mentioned string. So, I'm manually replacing the string with `""`.

```
 if(description.contains("Ã-Â"))
                description.replace("Ã-Â","");
```

But it's not working. Is there any better way to parse this string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like encoding trouble. What encoding is the document in? And what encoding is your program compiled with?

Comment: "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8"

Comment: Why are not using WebView instead of TextView for showing HTML content ?

Comment: We want to use native page

Comment: thanks..It was a encoding problem